# How to print a Qt dialog having scrollbar?

Tags: qt

I found sample code to print contents of a dialog. But if the dialog has scrollbar(vertical) sample code doesn't print all the contents, it prints only viewable contents of a dialog.

Below is the code:

```
QPainter p(printer);
Qpixmap pm = QPixmap::grabwidget(this);  // this(widget is QDialog having scrollbar etc)
p.drawPixmap(0,0,pm)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `QAbstractScrollArea` providing the scrollbars then you should grab its `viewport()` to paint it,

if it is an actual `QScrollArea` then use its `widget()`.

```
QPainter p(printer);
Qpixmap pm = QPixmap::grabwidget(this->scrollarea->widget()); 
p.drawPixmap(0,0,pm)
```

Comment: Still I find few things missing, even tried in passing contentsRect(), rect() as second argument...